# How to minimise a function containing double integrals

Tags: probability, integration, machine-learning

I'm trying to minimise this function. $$R(h)=\int_{(x,y)\in(\chi,Y)}{L(h(x),y)dP_0(x,y)}$$
where L(z,y) is just $(z-y)^2$

I tried to differentiate wrt h and set the derivative to zero, but I'm getting confused on how to successively put the $dh$ inside the integral. This is my attempt so far.
$$\frac{dR(h)}{dh}=\int2(h(x)-y)dP_0(x,y)=0$$
$$\int{h(x)dP_0(x,y)}=\int{ydP_0(x,y)}$$

The h(x) I get doesn't match the result, I'm supposed to get, which is $$h(x)=\int{ydP_0(x,y)}=E[Y|X=x]$$

Comment: Are you sure the $h$ you get doesn't match the result you're supposed to get? What are you doing next after getting $\int h\,dP=\int y\,dP$?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That's the issue, I don't know where to go forward from that. I assumed i went somewhere wrong with derivatives because I still have the integration sign on the left side of the expression I got.

Comment: 1. What you're really differentiating w.r.t. here, if I'm understanding the setup correctly, is $h(x)$ for a particular value of $x$. So the integral on the left is only over $y$ and you can take a factor outside the integral. 2. In "the result I'm supposed to get", are you sure you have quite the right expression in terms of integrals for $E[Y|X=x]$?